# How can I preload data for vue.js in Laravel Spark?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

According to the docs and examples, I have perfectly working code that functions great:

```
Vue.component('admin-competitions-index', {
data: function() {
    return {
        competitions: []
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.$http.get('/api/admin/competitions')
        .then(response => {
            this.competitions = response.data;
    });
},

methods: {
    /**
     * Toggle whether a competition is published or not.
     */
    togglePublished(competition) {
        Spark.patch(`/api/admin/competitions/togglePublished/${competition.id}`, this.togglePublishedForm)
            .then(response => {
                competition.is_published = response;
            });
    }
}
});
```

However, I'd like to change this code to save the extra request that is made on page load. I don't see a convention anywhere in Laravel or Spark where this is done. I'm guessing that all I need to do is set a JS variable but I'm not sure where it would be proper to do so.

I also understand that this kind of defeats the point of using vue for asynchronous loading, but nevertheless I would like to learn this. I think it will become more useful if I were to use vue for my @show restful requests where even if I wanted everything to load asynchronously I would at the very least have to supply vue with the competition ID that I want loaded.

Comment: So you want `competitions` to be solid instead of `[]` when the component inits? This doesn't save any request, in both ways, *one* request is made be the toggle method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works out of the box:

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
   var competition = {!! $competition !!};
</script>
@endsection
```